# Upgrade from a Beta managed package install to the full Release version

Tags: managed-package, deployment, beta-managed-package

In a sandbox I had the current production release v1.14 of a managed package installed.

In the developer Org I created a new v1.15 Beta managed package to test out the features for the next release. The Beta managed package was then installed in the Sandbox mentioned above.

After it was tested successfully a v1.15 release managed package was created with exactly the same content as the v1.15 (Beta 1) package.

When I tried to install the release v1.15 managed package in the sandbox I got the following package installer error:

> Cannot upgrade beta
>
> Package You cannot upgrade a beta package,
> because developers can make incompatible changes to a package that has
> been released as a beta. To install a newer version of the package,
> you must first uninstall the existing version.

**Is there no way to get the sandbox onto the new version of the managed package without uninstalling the Beta, and all the data, first?** Or is it a case of once a Beta managed package has been installed you have committed yourself to completely uninstalling the package?

I'd like to avoid downloading the automatically generated export file with the current package data. Then having to start from scratch reinstalling the latest managed package and then pushing the old data back in. In a full Org this wouldn't be such an issue as the process is automated, but a sandbox with limited storage is more time consuming due to the relationships that need to be maintained when putting the data in manually.

A quick search indicates I may have inflicted more work on myself by using the Beta managed package in this sandbox.

> "Beta packages are not upgradeable". Reference [How to upgrade a managed package](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/How-to-upgrade-a-managed-packakge/m-p/221419#M39068)

---

**Update**

Argh! This goes from bad to worse. Because there are a number (87!) of customizations in the sandbox with dependencies on the managed package I'll need to remove them first or the package uninstall process fails.

[image]

Comment: Based on [URGENT HELP NEEDED. Managed Package Issue](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/AppExchange-Directory-Packaging/URGENT-HELP-NEEDED-Managed-Package-Issue-Please-Read/m-p/180968#M2577) I'm going to see if Salesforce support can change the Beta package into a Release package. If it can be done in one direction then maybe it be go the other way too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have your answer right there, beta packages can't be upgraded.

You will have to uninstall to get to the latest version. SFDC should help you restore your managed package data (in the installed package page) to help you restore your data after the re-install process has completed.

However, if your data structure has changed very much between versions this might not be helpful, and you should review the data you get BEFORE you uninstall.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. The Idea [Improve Beta Packages - Upgrade or Uninstall](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XfLfAAK) seems like a good candidate to improve the situation in the future.

Comment: Another possible solution is to refresh the sandbox from production.

Comment: Gen2 managed packages still work this way.  Huge waste of time not to be able to upgrade beta managed packages in sandboxes.

Comment: I ran into this with 2GP just now and was able to work around this limitation by incrementing to a new patch release version and then creating, promoting, and installing a new package version, which installed successfully, upgrading the beta version.

Answer (score 6):

My first reponse was to laugh at your pain because it so closley resembles mine, but then I made myself sad.

You are 100% correct! Once you have a beta managed package installed the only way to install another version of the package in question is to uninstall the current version and **export and reimport all of your data in the process.**

Comment: Thanks for the sympathy :)
 Now if you'll excuse me I have to go an load some test data manually.